# How do i encrypt a password for Tuya Smart Lock Open API

Tags: encryption, aes, openapi, tuya

Keep in mind that I'm very new and lost when it comes to coding.

I'm trying to generate a temporary for a smart lock that uses the Tuya App using Postman.
I am currently stuck on the password as it requires it to be encrypted.
[password requirements from tuya](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI1vu.png)
It says that i need to decrypt the "ticket_key" (which i manage get through the "Get a temporary key for password encryption" request) using the "accessKey". Can anyone help me locate this accessKey and explain how i am supposed to encrypt and decrypt (do i need to create a program for it or is there one already available).

Thanks in advance!

I tried using ChatGPT to write me a program that encrypts and decrypts but didnt manage to get anything usable out of it.

Comment: As far as I can read the requirements there are just some steps to run: 1) get the ticket_key and the accessKey from the platform, 2) convert the ticket_key from hex encoding to binary format (maybe the accessKey needs this as well), 3) setup a decryption program with AES encryption is ECB mode and PKCS#7 (or #5 in Java, they are equals) and decrypt the ticket_key with it. As you didn't tag any program language it's difficult to give further help but please keep in mind that Stackoverflow is not a free coding platform - you need to do most of the work yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar challenge and managed to achieve the desired outcome through a JavaScript program. Below are the steps I followed, which can also be accomplished using only Postman and online tools:

1. Obtain Access Token:

   - **Endpoint:** `/v1.0/token?grant_type=1` (GET method)
   - **Description:** Acquire an access token from Tuya's API, essential for authentication and authorization to make further requests.
2. Request Access Key:

   - **Endpoint:** `/v1.0/devices/[device_id]/door-lock/password-ticket` (POST method)
   - **Description:** Use the acquired access token to request an access key (or password ticket) from Tuya's API, necessary for generating a new door lock password.
3. Decrypt Access Key:

   - **Description:** Decrypt the obtained ticket key using https://www.lddgo.net/en/encrypt/aes. Use the following settings: Mode=ECB, Padding=pkcs7padding, Input Format=Hex, Output Format=String, Password=Your Tuya project client secret (details at https://support.tuya.com/en/help/_detail/Kasgyvlkrcufp), Charset=UTF-8.
4. Encrypt Pin Code:

   - **Description:** Encrypt the chosen 7-digit pin code using the same online tool as above. Modify the password to the decrypted value from the previous step, Input Format=String, Output Format=Hex.
5. Create a Password:

   - **Endpoint:** `/v1.0/devices/[device_id]/door-lock/temp-password` (POST method)
   - **Description:** Submit the encrypted pin code with additional required details (effective and expiration time of the password) to Tuya's API. This is for creating a temporary password for the door lock. In the request body, include the encrypted pin code as "password", the ticket_id from step 2, and timestamps for the effective and invalid times, as shown in this example.

   {
   "password": "9c63efba8fb57e89319dff9117d3765a",
   "password_type": "ticket",
   "ticket_id": "cNOYOdpM",
   "effective_time": 1701187200000,
   "invalid_time": 1701360000000,
   "name": "test666",
   "time_zone": ""
   }

**Note:** For Postman users, it's recommended to use the Postman collection from https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/iot/set-up-postman-environment?id=Ka7o385w1svns. This collection includes pre-written JavaScript code that calculates the sign value for each request.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for how the implementation should look like for Node:

```
private static encrypt_AES_128(data: string, secretKey: string) {
    const key = CryptoJs.enc.Utf8.parse(secretKey);
    const encrypted = CryptoJs.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
        mode: CryptoJs.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJs.pad.Pkcs7,
    });
    return encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJs.enc.Hex);
}
private static decrypt_AES_128(data: string, secretKey: string) {
    const key = CryptoJs.enc.Utf8.parse(secretKey);
    const encryptedHexStr = CryptoJs.enc.Hex.parse(data);
    const encryptedBase64Str = CryptoJs.enc.Base64.stringify(encryptedHexStr);
    const decryptedData = CryptoJs.AES.decrypt(encryptedBase64Str, key, {
        mode: CryptoJs.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJs.pad.Pkcs7,
    });
    return decryptedData.toString(CryptoJs.enc.Utf8);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**